# Find greatest value of an angle

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am not sure how to go about the last bit of this problem.

> With respect to an origin $O$, the points $P$ and $Q$ have variable position vectors $p$ and $q$ respectively, given by, $$
> \begin{align}
> p &= (\cos t)i + (\sin t)j - k \\
> q &= (\cos 2t)i - (sin 2t)j + \frac12k
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where $t$ is a real parameter such that $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.
>
> Show that $p \cdot q = \cos 3t - \frac12$ and hence, or otherwise, find the greatest value of the $\angle{POQ}$.

I have worked out the first part of this problem like below,

$$
\begin{align}
p &= (\cos t, \sin t, - 1) \\
q &= (\cos 2t, -\sin 2t, \frac12)
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
p.q &= \cos t \cos 2t - \sin t \sin 2t - \frac12 \\
    &= \cos (t + 2t) - \frac12 \\
    &= \cos 3t - \frac12
\end{align}
$$

For finding the angle,

$$
\begin{align}
|p| &= \sqrt{\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t} = 1 \\
|q| &= \sqrt{\cos^2 2t + \sin^2 2t} = 1
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\cos \angle{POQ} &= \dfrac{p \cdot q}{|p| |q|} \\
         &= \cos 3t - \frac12
\end{align}
$$

This is the part I am unsure about. The problem asks for the maximum value of the angle and not the cosine of the angle. I could have gotten max cosine like,

Max $\cos 3t = 1$

Max $\cos POQ = 1 - \frac12 = 1/2$

Which would give $\frac\pi3$. But I don't think that's quite right, and doesn't match the given answer which is $2.82$ radians.

> How do I get the max of $\angle{POQ}$.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norms of $p$ and $q$ aren't right because you didn't include the last component in the sum of the squares of the components.

Also, to maximize the angle, you need to *minimize*, not maximize the cosine.

Comment: A Doh! moment if there ever was one. It makes sense now. Thanks for your help.